# Set distance between signature and enclosures in scrlttr2

Tags: scrlttr2, signatures

I am using the `scrlttr2` package to write a letter with enclosures. However, I do not like the default vertical distance between the signature and the list of enclosures. Currently in my Tex document, I have written something like this at the end of my letter:

```
\closing{Sincerly yours}
\setkomavar*{enclseparator}{Enclosures}
\encl{%
        Sweet picture
        Secret document
        Some more stuff
        }
```

In the resulting pdf it reads as

```
Sincerly yours


<My name>

Enclosures: Sweet picture
            Secret document
            Some more stuff
```

There is only approximately one line between `<My name>` and the list of enclosures. How can I increase this distance?

Answer (score 1):

You can patch either `\closing`

```
\AddToHook{cmd/closing/after}{\vskip \baselineskip}
```

or `\encl`

```
\AddToHook{cmd/encl/before}{\par\vskip \baselineskip}
```

to enlarge the vertical space before the list of enclosures by one baselineskip.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setkomavar{fromname}{My name}
\AddToHook{cmd/closing/after}{\vskip \baselineskip}
%\AddToHook{cmd/encl/before}{\par\vskip \baselineskip}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{%
Joanna Public\\
1 Hillside\\
SAMPLESTEAD\\
WX12 3YZ%
}
\opening{Dear Madam Chair,}
\lipsum[1]
\closing{Sincerly yours}
\setkomavar*{enclseparator}{Enclosures}
\encl{%
        Sweet picture\\
        Secret document\\
        Some more stuff\\
        }
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]